# Toolbar with RTL layout in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, layout, delphi-7, toolbar, right-to-left

The question is very simple - **how can I change a toolbar's layout to right-to-left** (i.e. icons are aligned to the right of the toolbar and their order is reversed - the first one is at the far right, the second one is on the left of it and so on) **in Delphi 7**?

`TToolBar` doesn't publish the `BiDiMode` and `ParentBiDiMode` properties and even if I publish them in an interceptor class, nothing changes when I set `BiDiMode` to `bdRightToLeft` (of course with `SysLocale.MiddleEast` = `True`).

I tried setting `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` to the toolbar with `SetWindowLong`, but the result is really messy -- the toolbar is repainted very badly. Plus the icons themselves are mirrored and I don't want that, I just want them in right-to-left order.

Comment: i think there is no way to do it. You can try add some separator on the left and then dynamically to set it size so your buttons to appears on the right.

Comment: That's my plan B, but I'm hoping to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi doesn't expose BiDiMode for TToolbar or TToolButton because the underlying Windows common ToolBar control doesn't support them. See the possible values for configuring ToolBars in the MSDN documentation for [ToolBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - none of the possible values for configuring it (including those available when sending `TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE` include anything related to toolbar LTR/RTL orientation.

You can configure horizontal or vertical orientation using `TB_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE` with the `TBSTYLE_EX_VERTICAL` flag (which is not recommended, according to the docs), but not LTR/RTR button alignment. You can configure the text directionality using [TB_SETDRAWTEXTFLAGS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `DT_RTLREADING`, but nothing that changes button alignment from the left side to the right side of the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

How align last button on right:

Push panel before button, set Caption:='' and BevelOuter:=bvNone and in procedure FormResize():

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
    panelSep.Width:=0;
    panelSep.Width:=ToolBar1.Width - tbLastButton.Left - tbLastButton.Width;
end;
```